# How to access triangulates in a 3d model that was imported in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d-modeling

I have a 3d model of a city. It is in collada format and ina dae file. I imported 3d model to unity but I don't know how can I access the objects of this 3d model with c# script.Because I am new with coding stuff. I am trying to learn bot unity and c# at the same time and I think this is a painful process.I want to access and manipulate the triangles in this 3d model. You can see the model in the attaching picture[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mesh` class contains `triangles` array, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-triangles.html):

> The array is a list of triangles that contains indices into the vertex array

Comment: Thanks for answer can you describe the syntax for this according to my object (new_scene1_0)

Comment: because myscript does not work